# client-side storage of private key

Tags: javascript

I know that we're not supposed to "trust" the client because JavaScript is an interpreted language and it is trivial to inspect variables, even with code obfuscation and uglifying.

Still, I wanted to ask the following :

- is it possible to store a variable that is *very hard* to access? i.e. some kind of javascript trigger that is able to detect when the event loop has been stopped (and react accordingly?)
- i.e. I wanted to store a secret value in the client but I didn't want clients to actually go and look at what the value actually was.

thanks

Follow-up : even if the client can find the variable, is it possible to detect tampering of the variable? i.e. some polling between the client/server such that if the client event loop doesn't respond periodically every X seconds then the server considers the client compromised?

Comment: "Very hard" is a relative term. You could do something like what .Net does with viewstate and create a hash inside whatever method of storage you want, but given enough time, it can be decrypted.

Comment: @Shmiddty .. where "enough time" means "eternity" or "not gonna happen before people stop caring" for all practical purposes for a properly-configured ViewState encryption. Also, encryption (alone) doesn't stop [limited] inspection, storage, and replay.

Answer (score 4):

If the client has it, the client can find it.